# jQuery .animate() not working and cannot figure out why

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

So I am trying to animate some changes to my navbar using jQuery. Everything else like .css() or .append() will work in the exact same way I am trying to use .animate() but am getting no response. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the HTML I am trying to animate:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom" id="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topNav">
                <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">A1 Auto Care</a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-right" id="topNav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#visit:facebook" id="facebookBtn" class="text-center"><span id="facebookLogo" class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
    $(window).on( "scroll", function(){

    if($(document).scrollTop() >= 10){
        $('#navbar').animate({border:"2px solid red"}, 300);
    }
});
```

Comment: As far as I know, jQuery `animate(...)` is only able to animate properties with numeric values (like `borderWidth`), but no colors. Nevertheless, you can also use `jQuery.Color` plugin or `jQuery.UI` library (extends the `animate(...)` method and allows to animate colors)

Comment: Ahhhh! Thank you. Did not even realize this. Appreciate the help :)